# The Mystery Of the Loopy Rope

Tags: word, rhyme, cryptic-clues

The answer is a single English word.

> Fish trap backward. Two handfuls mock.
>   River in a car, a spice and a rock.
>   Gemstone in sugar, nethermost shade.
>   The alien called, all disarrayed.

Bonus clue for @GentlePurpleRain. All others: no peeking!

> Lip, pen: lure.

Comment: Oops. I peeked.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain *sigh* you snooze, you lose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is...

> GARNET.

Fish trap backward. Two handfuls mock.

> def "fish trap" (GAR NET), and backward "TEN RAG" (ten: 2 times 5 fingers - thanks, Jon!)

River in a car, a spice and a rock.

> G(ARNE)T; def "spice and a rock" cinnamon stone is a type of garnet

Gemstone in sugar, nethermost...

> su**GAR NET**hermost; def "Gemstone"

...shade. The alien called, all disarrayed.

> def "shade" (garnet is a shade of red); ET RANG*

Bonus clue:

> GENTLEPURPLERAIN anagrammed is LIP PEN LURE GARNET.

And the title hides the word

> Pyrope, a type of garnet.

Comment: two handfuls=10, to mock=to rag. ten rag backwards gives ..